# Is there a workaround for the following VSTO Word 2010 word addin click once deployment error?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, clickonce

When deploying a Word Add in , which publishes without error. I get the following error after the files have been copied.

I do not have much to go on. This is the stack trace.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IActContext.ApplicationBasePath(UInt32 Flags, String& ApplicationPath)
>      at System.ActivationContext.get_ApplicationDirectory()
>      at System.AppDomainSetup..ctor(ActivationArguments activationArguments)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.CreateAppDomainSetup(ActivationContext context, Uri deploymentManifestUri, AddInInstallationStatus installStatus)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Comment: What is the full path you are installing to? It sounds like the path is invalid or too long.

Comment: I am deploying/ invoking the setup.exe file in  c:\deploy?  I purposely deploy to a top level folder to avoid publish errors revolving around long paths/filenames.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>here's an answer to what you are looking for:-</strike>

the problem:-
open Process Monitor during the failed update and see if Winword.exe is browsing the following registry key->
HKCU\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0\Marks\mmiw..vsto_510943deeecbc925_0002.0000_2055f5031035ea75\appid

in this someone managed to check the Compatibility Mode checkbox for Word, running it default under Windows XP SP2 (see if you can make the program compatibile with your system in short).

if this is not the issue

Then read further into this :- [deploy a VS 2008 SP1 Word 2007](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/14f5ee63-fa59-42d3-ab8a-6bfbe4917907)

---

There is another post i have found on this topic ***[HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/7ab8d7a2-9d37-402d-98db-ac74f8b04b14).*** it shows a possible work around that you could try to get a result? i'm not entirely sure but in this, the developer was using outlook 2008, i think he removed the instances of outlook within his code and re-implemented parts of it and left out others. Perhaps this could be a temporary fix or help you understand what the problem is?

---

(I'm sorry my answers aren't so clear, i don't have much time for stack overflow at the moment, i will clean up the answer when i have more time(it will flow)) ++ this is all i can find regarding this error, but there are people with the same issue on the Microsoft forums, maybe you could find an answer faster on there? if you follow the links I've posted you should be able to find some information that might be able to give you a decent fix.

PS. if this doesn't work, reply asap and i will search asap, i think I've found something else which might be of use, just have to understand it myself before i post.

Comment: Process Monitor? So you mean install process monitor?  HKCU is an abbrv?

Comment: He means [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and HKCU is an abbreviation for HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: In addition the explanation is not lucid.

Comment: are you trying to copy the files over, then publish the copied files?? I'm not too sure what the question is asking. ++ Check Additions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem too after messing with some dependencies. None of the noted solutions worked (either on MSDN or here).

How I fixed it:

- Find an old published version that worked.
- Find the .dll.manifest file.
- Diff that manifest with the one that is erroring.

In my case, I saw that a .dll was incorrectly referenced there (I thus had a v2 of it and a v4). I removed this reference and, thank god, it works.

Comment: lol. Thank god it works! That's how we all feel sometimes. BTW a far more cogent answer than the jokers answers above, who robbed me of me points.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, there was an unnecessary reference in manifest file, although unnecessary reference may not create problems but good to remove them. in my case, reference was of another vsto which was being updated on every publish but in erroring vsto, it was remaining unchanged. i used this technique.
How I fixed it:

Find an old published version that worked.
Find the .dll.manifest file.
Diff that manifest with the one that is erroring.